# Selenium IDE 1.0.2 in Firefox 3.5 on Mac

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, firefox-addon

I've tried installing Selenium IDE from their website. The newest version - 1.0.2 -  installs fine. After restarting Firefox, I go to "Tools" > "Selenium IDE", and this window opens:[image]

No more happens. I can access the menus of Selenium (Create New Test Case, etc.) but clicking them doesn't have any effect.

I am using Firefox 3.5.3 on Mac OS 10.6.1. The version I installed of Selenium IDE was 1.0.2 from http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.0.2/

Is there any way to make it work? Or is it just me who cannot make it work?

Comment: Working fine for me with Selenium IDE 1.0.2, Mac OS 10.6.1, and Firefox 3.5.4. Pretty sure it was working with Firefox 3.5.3 too.

Comment: This exact thing happend to me a while ago. I think it's a problem with a conflicting add-on. Try unintstalling all your addons and then reinstall them one by one. (although, it could be some combination that will take ages to work out, or it could be something else entierly). 

Perhaps a better approach would be to re-download and install firefox, but give the app a different name. Launch this app and just install the IDE add on. 

Let me know if it works. (I'm not posting this as an answer because it's little more than a shot in the dark).

Comment: @Rodreegez: It worked. I created a new Firefox profile and installed only the Selenium IDE extension.

Comment: great stuff! I wonder why it happens? Still, glad we know the answer...

Comment: Maybe you could list a few of the other extensions you had installed? We could try to replicate it and find out which caused the problem.

Comment: No need, Dave. Thanks anyways but it is perfectly fine for me to write and run the tests in a "clean" environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the conflicting extension are themes, for not having to create a completely clean profile and loose all your add-ons, try using firefox in it's default theme and see if that works better.